# Python lxml XPath: Invalid expression (optional child)

Tags: python, xpath, lxml

I need to extract text from a website. The website has two different kinds of structures, where one has an additional element before the main text.

I try to extract the text as follows:

```
//div[contains(@id, "text")]/(p|.)/text()
```

As far as I see, eTree's Xpath doesn't like the `(p|.)`. Is there another brief way to write this so that lxml doesn't complain? I know I can just write both out and put an or between them, but this option above saves quite a lot of typing (and works considering pure XPath).

Thanks!

EDIT
Here are two small exemplary snippets for the two cases (simplified):

Without child:

```
<div class="article_text">
    ...
    <div id="bodytext"...>
    "yadda yadda here be dragons"
    </div>
</div>
```

With child:

```
<div class="article_text">
    ...
    <div id="bodytext">
        <p>
            "Here be paragraphed dragons"
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

EDIT 2:
It's not exactly about this specific case, but rather about lxml directly - I'm extrating texts from a lot of different sites, and this "optional child" is rather common - my question would be if there is another option (different writing) for this syntax, or does lxml just not accept it and I have to "OR" it all out?

EDIT 3:
Something that I came across just now would be: the news site has different kinds of articles, sometimes a so-called "infobox", which is not desired to extract. So I would do `//main/(div[not(contains(@class, "infobox"))]|.)/p/text()`, to exclude this specific div, but include other divs or other kinds of tags in between. The text is in some pages wrapped in divs, in other wrappend in multiple divs, sometimes in spans etc. Meaning "OR" it all together would yield an extremely/unnecessary complex XPath compared to the solution there - but as said, lxml does not seem to like it.

Comment: Share HTML for both cases. Also try `//div[contains(@id, "text")]//text()`

Comment: @Andersson Consider `"<html><div id='text'><p>123</p>456<div>789</div></div></html>"`, OP wants `['123', '456']`, your xpath will return `['123', '456', '789']`.

Comment: @kitman0804 , did you see HTML source?

Comment: @Andersson No. It's just my understanding of OP's problem. Let's wait for his clarification. ;)

Comment: Updated question.The xpath should go for multiple different files which are slightly different (here e.g. the optional child), sometimes more such things which ina n XPath tester works flawlessly, but not in lxml's eTree Xpath

Comment: Did you tried the expanded version just to make sure the OR operator works in lxml? `//div[contains(@id, "text")]/text()|//div[contains(@id, "text")]/p/text()`

Answer (score 0):

If you want all descendants' text, you can do (I joined both your examples into one XML document):

```
>>> doc.xpath('//div[contains(@id, "text")]//text()')
['\n    "yadda yadda here be dragons"\n    ', '\n        ', '\n            "Here be paragraphed dragons"\n        ', '\n    ']
```

Note the `//` before `text()`, and the output is a flat list.

If you want the output split on node, you can do something along the lines:

```
>>> for node in doc.xpath('//div[contains(@id,"text")]'):
    print((''.join(node.xpath('.//text()')).strip()))
"yadda yadda here be dragons"
"Here be paragraphed dragons"
```